# unmarked block header after Garbage Collection sweep phase

Tags: garbage-collection, operating-system

I'm new to Garbage Collection, just a question on unmarked block header after sweep. Below is from my textbook:

[image]

**Initially, the heap in the Figure consists of six allocated blocks, each of which
is unmarked. Block 3 contains a pointer to block 1. Block 4 contains pointers
to blocks 3 and 6. The root points to block 4. After the mark phase, blocks 1,
3, 4, and 6 are marked because they are reachable from the root. Blocks 2 and
5 are unmarked because they are unreachable. After the sweep phase, the two
unreachable blocks are reclaimed to the free list.**

But I don't know what's the status of block 3 and block 6, why they are not marked as "unmarked" just like block 1?

Comment: This is very hard to answer without reading the surrounding context in the textbook. Which book is this? Which page?

Comment: @mjwills   CSAPP(Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective)  page 841

Comment: The actual question should be, why is block 1 “marked as unmarked”?  Isn’t not being marked already “unmarked”?